# Rendering Problems in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to learn App Development using Youtube tutorials. I did exactly as it was shown in video, but after 2 or 3 times restarting the Android Studio, it is not showing the workspace. This is what was coming on screen, [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r88RS.jpg)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: check the style for activity.

Comment: i'm really new at this could you be a bit more specific.

Comment: if you mean to change the theme i tried changing that @Android

Comment: @Android i think i found a temporary solution but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly understand what was wrong, but when I changed from API 23 to API 19, it started showing the screen.

Comment: Yeah, I get this problem everytime a new API is released. API 23 is still new, anda so I don't think the rendering engine for Android Studio works for it quite yet. As long as you are developing simple apps, dropping the API is fine.